# Workflow for git merging and cherry picking in a migrated subversion repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

My team is transitioning from SVN to git, and one of the things I'm trying to sort out is a long term branching strategy.  In SVN we had our trunk, and then several release branches which each represented a major platform revision (V1, V2, etc).  Our workflow for something like a bug fix or patch was to make the change in a branch (e.g. in V1), and then merge the commits to V2, and trunk.

Now, in git, the same release branches exist as git branches, but merging is much more problematic because of the amount the branches differ from each other.  What I'd like to do is have someone create a topic branch from V1, create a fix, and then merge that topic branch.  This works great for merging back to V1, but merging to V2 resulted in 1300 merge conflicts when I tried it because of the divergent history.  The only solution I've found so far is that I can do this:

- Create a topic branch from V1, and create a fix in the topic branch
- Merge this to v1
- Cherry pick the commits from the topic branches to V2 and master

Is there a better workflow to look at here?  From what I've read, this seems like doing git "wrong", but given the source material, is there really any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Cherry picking creates a new commit with the same content but a different parent.  That makes it a different commit.  So you should not cherry pick to branches that expect to merge later with the original commits (the cherries).

Scenario with back and forward porting topics:

```
...--o--A--o--o--o--o--o--o--F [master]
        \                    \
         \...--D [V1]         \...--H [V2]
               \                    \
                \...--Q [topic]      \...--J [topicJ]
```

Constraints:

- D doesn't belong on V2
- H doesn't belong on V1
- we want topic commits `(D..Q]` for V2 (forward port)
- we want topicJ commits `(H..J]` for V1 (back port)

After successfully merging topic to V1, it looks like:

```
...--o--A--o--o--o--o--o--o--F [master]
        \                    \____
         \...D...--Q [V1][topic]  \...--H [V2]
                                   \
                                    \...--J [topicJ]
```

So yes, attempting to rebase topic onto V2 is effectively the same as trying to rebase the entire V1 platform branch (a self-defeating purpose)... **unless** we are more specific.  We could cherry-pick for every intended commit by hash, or when that gets unwieldy, we could use the `--onto` option for rebase:

```
git rebase --onto V2 D topic
# or, *before* merge that would have been even clearer
git rebase --onto V2 V1 topic
```

For more info on `rebase --onto`, see here: http://pivotallabs.com/git-rebase-onto/

This is pretty high level git fu, but it is a lot better than trying to script up cherry-picks all day.

Comment: True,but won't that just rebase back to a common ancestor? Say that  v1 branched off the trunk at A, and v2 branched off at F. If V1 has commit D, and V2 has commit H (which diverged),and I create a branch off of H to fix something that's common, when I rebase J (the topic) back to v2, won't it try to rebase everything in the topic (Commits J and H) onto v2 (and not just J)? I was under the impression that the only difference between a rebase and a cherry pick was that a rebase would trace back to a divergence point, while a cherry pick specifies the specific commits that you want to recreate

Comment: Ah, I see your concern.  Updating answer.